# ExtJS 4 grid.Panel how to use dataIndex of a sub-element

Tags: extjs, multidimensional-array, grid

I am trying to display data in an ExtJS grid.  I have it mostly working, but in my array of data, I have an array containing additional data (named 'extra').   I need to display fields from this sub-array:

Here is some example data coming back from my server in to ExtJS (Direct proxy) - this is one record:

```
{"type":"rpc","tid":6,"action":"EncounterService","method":"getRecords","result":[{"id":"20","addedDate":"2011-09-22 11:02:04","clientID":"19","extra":{"gender":"M"}}]}
```

In my Ext.grid.Panel, I have a Store set that has a model that looks like this:

```
Ext.define('ESDB.model.Encounter', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: ['id','addedDate','clientID','extra']
});
```

Finally, my Ext.grid.panel, my columns are defined:

```
 this.columns = [
          {header: 'id', dataIndex: 'id', flex: 1}
              {header: 'gender', dataIndex: 'extra.gender', flex: 1}
   ]
```

The id will display - as will any other field in the base 'result' array.   However, I the 'extra.gender' does not work.    How can I add a column and have it display the gender row from the 'extra' array object within my 'result' array object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know Ext not support that kind of nested data out of box. You can extend model and override get/set methods to support this. Below is example of how you can override get method.

```
var model = Ext.define("Ext.data.reader.SomeModel", {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
        {name: 'name'},
        {name: 'extra.gender'}
    ],
    get: function(field){
        if (field.indexOf('.') !== -1) {
            var parts = field.split('.');
            var value = Ext.data.Model.prototype.get.call(this, parts[0]);

            return Ext.isObject(value) ? value[parts[1]] : undefined;
        }
        return Ext.data.Model.prototype.get.call(this, field);
    }
})
```

Set contains more code, but it's still quite simple to override.

Answer (score 4):

The proper way to do this is by using a mapping.

http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.data.Field-cfg-mapping

Configuring the field like so:

```
        {name: 'gender', mapping: 'extra.gender'}
```

Will give you a field named gender that has been extracted out of the proper objects, etc

Answer (score 1):

You could use the render function of the column:

```
this.columns = [
{
    flex: 1,
    header: 'gender',
    dataIndex: 'extra',
    renderer: function(extra){
        return extra.gender;
    }
}]
```