# extjs nested json

Tags: extjs

Getting conflicting information from various places on whether or not nested json is available in extjs. NB using Sencha Architect which may be complicating things...

I have a client json object being returnd via a store/ajax proxy. I can not access anything beyond the first level.

JSON looks like this:

```
    {
    "client": {
        "0": {
            "id": "12345",
            "type_id": "3",
            "association_id": "0",
            "is_active": "1",
            "manager_id": "2",
            "business_name": null,
            "has_payroll": "0",
            "business_proprietor_contact_id": null,
            "date_created": "1358893243",
            "date_modified": "1358893243"
        },
        "contacts": [
            {
                "id": "1",
                "client_id": "12345",
                "contact_id": "1",
                "is_primary": "0",
                "display_priority": "0",
                "relationship": "Client",
                "friendly_name": "Homer",
                "contact": [
                    {
                        "id": "1",
                        "surname": "Mr.",
                        "first_name": "Homer",
                        "middle_name": "J",
                        "last_name": "Simpson",
                        "client_id": "12345",
                        "date_created": "1356038714",
                        "date_modified": null
                    },
                    {
                        "addresses": [
                            {
                                "id": "1",
                                "contact_id": "1",
                                "address_id": "16",
                                "is_mailing_address": "0",
                                "is_primary_address": "0",
                                "display_priority": "0",
                                "address": {
                                    "0": {
                                        "id": "16",
                                        "address": "5 Dirt Rd",
                                        "address2": "",
                                        "city": "TAXMASTER",
                                        "state": "NY",
                                        "zip_code": "454545",
                                        "country": "USA",
                                        "other": null,
                                        "phone": null,
                                        "fax": null,
                                        "display_priority": null,
                                        "is_mailing_address": "1"
                                    },
                                    "data": [
                                        {
                                            "id": "10",
                                            "label": "Phone",
                                            "value": "BUT WHO WAS",
                                            "date_created": "1356104685",
                                            "date_modified": "1357142782",
                                            "user_id": null,
                                            "display_priority": null,
                                            "client_id": null,
                                            "contact_id": null,
                                            "account_id": null,
                                            "business_id": null,
                                            "address_id": "16",
                                            "is_deleted": "0"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "id": "14",
                                            "label": "Fax",
                                            "value": "simile",
                                            "date_created": "1356557379",
                                            "date_modified": "1357142782",
                                            "user_id": null,
                                            "display_priority": null,
                                            "client_id": null,
                                            "contact_id": null,
                                            "account_id": null,
                                            "business_id": null,
                                            "address_id": "16",
                                            "is_deleted": "0"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "id": "17",
                                            "label": "Also Known as:",
                                            "value": "DUDE",
                                            "date_created": "1357141357",
                                            "date_modified": "1357142782",
                                            "user_id": null,
                                            "display_priority": null,
                                            "client_id": null,
                                            "contact_id": null,
                                            "account_id": null,
                                            "business_id": null,
                                            "address_id": "16",
                                            "is_deleted": "0"
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "id": "6",
                                "contact_id": "1",
                                "address_id": "26",
                                "is_mailing_address": "0",
                                "is_primary_address": "0",
                                "display_priority": "0",
                                "address": {
                                    "0": {
                                        "id": "26",
                                        "address": "1 Lift Road",
                                        "address2": "",
                                        "city": "Tony Beach",
                                        "state": "KS",
                                        "zip_code": "15151",
                                        "country": "USA",
                                        "other": null,
                                        "phone": null,
                                        "fax": null,
                                        "display_priority": null,
                                        "is_mailing_address": "0"
                                    },
                                    "data": [
                                        {
                                            "id": "18",
                                            "label": "Phone:",
                                            "value": "cool phone number",
                                            "date_created": "1357141527",
                                            "date_modified": "1357141527",
                                            "user_id": null,
                                            "display_priority": null,
                                            "client_id": null,
                                            "contact_id": null,
                                            "account_id": null,
                                            "business_id": null,
                                            "address_id": "26",
                                            "is_deleted": "0"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "id": "19",
                                            "label": "Note:",
                                            "value": "cool note",
                                            "date_created": "1357141527",
                                            "date_modified": "1357141527",
                                            "user_id": null,
                                            "display_priority": null,
                                            "client_id": null,
                                            "contact_id": null,
                                            "account_id": null,
                                            "business_id": null,
                                            "address_id": "26",
                                            "is_deleted": "0"
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            },
                        ],
                        "data": [
                            {
                                "id": "1",
                                "label": "asdf",
                                "value": "dfdfefefefef",
                                "date_created": "1356038714",
                                "date_modified": "1356040822",
                                "user_id": "2",
                                "display_priority": "0",
                                "client_id": null,
                                "contact_id": "1",
                                "account_id": null,
                                "business_id": null,
                                "address_id": null,
                                "is_deleted": "0"
                            },
                            {
                                "id": "2",
                                "label": "asfd",
                                "value": "152151",
                                "date_created": "1356038714",
                                "date_modified": "1356040822",
                                "user_id": null,
                                "display_priority": "2",
                                "client_id": null,
                                "contact_id": "1",
                                "account_id": null,
                                "business_id": null,
                                "address_id": null,
                                "is_deleted": "0"
                            },
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": "7",
                "client_id": "12345",
                "contact_id": "11",
                "is_primary": "0",
                "display_priority": "0",
                "relationship": "None",
                "friendly_name": "Mary Jane",
                "contact": {
                    "0": {
                        "id": "11",
                        "surname": "",
                        "first_name": "Mary Jane",
                        "middle_name": "",
                        "last_name": "Simpson",
                        "client_id": null,
                        "date_created": "1357145795",
                        "date_modified": null
                    },
                    "7": {
                        "addresses": [
                            {
                                "id": "11",
                                "contact_id": "11",
                                "address_id": "33",
                                "is_mailing_address": "0",
                                "is_primary_address": "0",
                                "display_priority": "0",
                                "address": {
                                    "0": {
                                        "id": "33",
                                        "address": "33 Street",
                                        "address2": "",
                                        "city": "NY",
                                        "state": "NY",
                                        "zip_code": "06830",
                                        "country": "USA",
                                        "other": null,
                                        "phone": null,
                                        "fax": null,
                                        "display_priority": null,
                                        "is_mailing_address": "0"
                                    },
                                    "data": [
                                        {
                                            "id": "31",
                                            "label": "Fax:",
                                            "value": "asdfasdf",
                                            "date_created": "1357145905",
                                            "date_modified": "1357145939",
                                            "user_id": null,
                                            "display_priority": null,
                                            "client_id": null,
                                            "contact_id": null,
                                            "account_id": null,
                                            "business_id": null,
                                            "address_id": "33",
                                            "is_deleted": "0"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "id": "32",
                                            "label": "Fax:",
                                            "value": "sadfsadf",
                                            "date_created": "1357145905",
                                            "date_modified": "1357145905",
                                            "user_id": null,
                                            "display_priority": null,
                                            "client_id": null,
                                            "contact_id": null,
                                            "account_id": null,
                                            "business_id": null,
                                            "address_id": "33",
                                            "is_deleted": "0"
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        ],
                        "data": [
                            {
                                "id": "29",
                                "label": "Phone:",
                                "value": "asdfsadf",
                                "date_created": "1357145833",
                                "date_modified": "1357145833",
                                "user_id": "2",
                                "display_priority": null,
                                "client_id": null,
                                "contact_id": "11",
                                "account_id": null,
                                "business_id": null,
                                "address_id": null,
                                "is_deleted": "0"
                            },
                            {
                                "id": "30",
                                "label": "Email:",
                                "value": "dsfgdsfg",
                                "date_created": "1357145855",
                                "date_modified": "1357145855",
                                "user_id": "2",
                                "display_priority": null,
                                "client_id": null,
                                "contact_id": "11",
                                "account_id": null,
                                "business_id": null,
                                "address_id": null,
                                "is_deleted": "0"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
        "notes": [
            {
                "id": "5",
                "client_id": "12345",
                "label": "This is a HomerHomer Note",
                "value": "This is from Homer's Dashboard Notes.",
                "contact_id": null,
                "address_id": null,
                "account_id": null,
                "account_data_id": null,
                "account_credential_id": null,
                "payment_id": null,
                "contact_log_id": null,
                "user_id": "2",
                "bill_id": null,
                "is_deleted": "0",
                "date_created": "1357148256",
                "date_modified": "1357148256"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/8318589/183254 nested JSON isn't available. According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/5604594/183254 it *is* available, but has to be in a certain format.

I did a little test based on the API docs format:

```
{
    results: 2000,
    rows: [
        { id: 1, firstname: 'Bill', occupation: 'Gardener', cool: {neat: 'wow'} },
        { id: 2, firstname: 'Ben' , occupation: 'Horticulturalist' },
    ]
}
```

with this coming in, I can call everything from a tpl. In particular, `cool.neat` prints `wow`. However, changing `cool` to `cool:[{neat:'wow}]` breaks. So it seems nested json partially works -- likely only partially because I'm doing something wrong.

My thinking was that it'd make sense to do a single request to the api and gather all the needed info, parse it, and send it out to components rather than creating proxies for every group of data that is needed. I may be wrong...

Along with needed guidance/facepunches I have 2 questions:

1) Is it possible/practical to try and do what I'm doing? i.e. trying to use a single request to gather the data for multiple components?

2) Is there a way to debug data from tpl?

This is extjs 4.1 via Sencha Architect

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this same issue. The only way I could get around it (I tried mapping and several other solutions) is basically have a main store and substores. Get the information from ajax and bring it into the main store. Have a "load" listener and when it loads, check to see if the inforamtion needs to be passed to the other store(s).

Set all the substores autoload property to false and never load them.

i.e:

```
load: function(t,records,successful,eOpts) {
    var substores [{store: nameOfStore, root: rootPropInTheJson},
                   {store...etc...etc..];
    for (var i = 0; i < substores.length; i++) {
        if (pathtoroot* != undefined) {
            substores[i].store.add(pathtojsonroot)
        }
    }
}
```

At least, this is what I think you meant. If this is what you meant, then yes, I found it practical, and I don't know the answer to the second question.

Comment: I assume you have some other vars set? `pathtoroot*` ? typo? At any rate, I keep getting `Uncaught TypeError: Object mySubStore has no method 'add'`. Also, you calling this from a load listener in the main stores' constructor? Thanks!

Comment: The random vars were just fillers. You put the name of the var with your store there. If you are doing it correctly, using add on the variable with your store will just add records to it. So you basically end up figuring out if the record needs to be added and then you push it out if needed. Can you post the code that is giving you the type error, as well as the store declaration. And yes, it's inside the main stores load listener

Comment: And the * was because I meant to add a note at the bottom mentioning that the path to the root ends up being something like:

    t.data.items[i].raw[substores[i].root][j]. 

another thing to note is you may, instead of looking for the root, look for a value inside the root. Maybe an id?

    t.data.items[0].raw[substores[i].root][j].id

Comment: `    var substores = [{store: 'contactStore', root: 'contacts' }];
    for (var i = 0; i < substores.length; i++) {
        if (store.data.items[i].raw[substores[i].root] != undefined) {
            substores[i].store.add('contact');
        }
    }` generates the no method 'add' type error. Do the stores I'm trying to add have to be instantiated first?

Comment: store isn't a string. You can do it 2 ways:

If you have the store created like this: 

`var firstStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {`

then you would do `store: firstStore`

If you want to use the storeId, then you could use `store: Ext.getStore('firstStore')`

Another issue that I see is that you are doing .add('contact'). By pathtojsonroot, I meant something like t.data.items[0].raw['root']